# Hierarchical logic for uses-feature?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an Android app that has an optional feature using the camera. So I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
```

in my manifest. Since the app works just fine without the feature I have

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Now the interesting thing is that the Motodev Studio app validator reports that I should add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

however I would have thought that required value is inherited. I can not find any documentation on that so should I just put it in for good measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've probably seen by now, the hierarchy is from more specific to least.  This means that if you specify android.hardware.camera.autofocus then android.hardware.camera is implied.  Not the reverse.  If you really need an autofocus camera, then you need to specify it. Otherwise you will get whatever camera the device has, which may or may not be AF or have a flash.

-E

Comment: Hm... I would have thought it makes sense to inherit a required false down to more specific. But in a way I understand if it does not. Maybe it might be easiest if there is no inheritance at all. In any case there seems to be no documentation about it apart from the source..

Comment: Correct about the docs. The person who explained it to me said she figured it out only because she happened to have the various hardware that represented those configurations and was writing samples explicitly to exercise those permissions.